# How can I get the spatial correlation between two datsets in r?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two arrays:

```
data1=array(-10:30, c(2160,1080,12))
data2=array(-20:30, c(2160,1080,12))
#Add in some NAs
ind <- which(data1 %in% sample(data1, 1500))
data1[ind] <- NA
```

One is **modelled** global gridded data (lon,lat,month) and the other, global gridded **observations** (lon,lat,month).
I want to assess how 'skillful' the modelled data is at recreating the obs. I think the best way to do this is with a spatial correlation between the datasets. How can I do that?

I tried a straightforward `x<-cor(data1,data2)` but that just returned `x<-NA_real_`.
Then I was thinking that I probably have to break it up by month or season. So, just looking at one month `x<-cor(data1[,,1],data2[,,1])` it returned a matrix of size 1080*1080 (most of which are NAs).

How can I get a spatial correlation between these two datasets? i.e. I want to see where the modelled data performs 'well' i.e. has high correlation with observations, or where it does badly (low correlation with observations).

Comment: I don't think the `ind <- which(data1 %in% sample(data1, 1500))` is doing what you want. It makes (almost) everything NA, because `sample(data1, 1500)` returns numbers 1500 random numbers between -10 and 30 and the rest of the code replaces those values with `NA`. Apart from that, `cor()` has an argument `use`, which you can set as `use = "complete.obs"` to drop NAs in the calculation of correlation.

Comment: @Bas I was just trying to replicate what was happening in my real dataset (non-land areas are represented by NAs). Is what you're suggesting `use=complete.obs' the best way to ignore the sea NAs?

Comment: Yes, it throws away the pairs where `data1` or `data2` is NA, which is what you want. It is not a _spatial_ correlation, though, which (as I understood from https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/3-spauto.html) is something different. I have never used that, but you might want to walk through that article and try to use that on your dataset.